# Matching for Longitudinal Data

Tags: anova, modeling, panel-data

I have some data for a Gyms usage over the last 5 years.  The data consists of datetime stamp, the number of people in the gym at that time and date, and the weather (e.g. temperature and if it was precipitating).

I'm tasked with determining if rain discourages people from coming to the gym.  It isn't so clear to me how best to analyze this because

- It may not rain for an entire day, only for part of a day
- The effect of time of day may confound any effect of rain on usage

How should I best approach this?  I suppose I could use an ANCOVA, right?  Just looking for some ideas.